# Data table paging using server side without TotalPage count

Tags: c#, sql, datatables

I'm using **server side** paging

Fetching data from database

While fetching all records count for total page count facing loading issue

I want to implement paging functionality without page number only **next** and **previous**.

I am also sharing my code
[image: server side paging]

Comment: Please paste your code as Text, not a screenshot.  Not only is it difficult to read, but it is impossible to copy paste if needed for replicating and testing purposes.   Please also state what Database you are using.  DBs are not equal, and the solution may depend on this.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmithi try to paste code its getting error while save

Comment: I have a large amount of data in table while i'm try to get total records it's taking more  time , so i want to implement data table without total records count

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Comment: @jarlhI have 5 table joins in my query index thing is not working for me